# How to compare a data frame with duplicates and a vector?

Tags: r, dataframe, logical-operators, sample

I have a data frame in which some ids appear more than once. I sampled this ids uniquely and now I have a vector with the sampled ids. Now I need to create a logical that tells me which rows in the data frame have ids that also appear on my sample.

I have tried the match function, but it selects only the first appearance and I need all appearances.

I have also tried merge but the dataset is to large so there is no memory to do it.

Comment: `mydf$idcol %in% idsample` for a logical index.

Comment: @PierreLafortune What is the etiquette in this situation? Does my answer add enough beyond your comment, or should I delete it? I'm fine either way.

Comment: No don't delete, I left a comment, you can answer to expand with examples

Comment: @PierreLafortune Ok. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `%in%` to get a logical vector and `which` together with `in` to get the row indices. Here is a reproducible example that contains duplicate IDs.

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(id=sample(1:80, 100, replace=TRUE), b=rnorm(100))
mySample <- seq(1, 80, by=6)

#logical vector length of nrow(df)
myRows <- df$id %in% mySample
# row indices
myIndices <- which(df$id %in% mySample)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what you can do using `match` (as you were trying this function):

```
x=match(df$id, mySample, nomatch = 0) > 0
```

Which gives you a logical vector which is `TRUE` if `df$id` appears in `mySample` and `FALSE` otherwise.

To retrieve the respective indices:

```
which(x==T)
```